# Installing ActionbarSherlock with Android Studio?

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-studio

As many other Android Developers I installed Android Studio, but how do I install actionbarsherlock into Android Studio?

Any help? I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: I know it's possible since they discussed ActionbarSherlock in the keynote today.  I've tried migrating a project that includes ABS from Eclipse with no joy.  Getting DAX errors complaining about multiple copies of the support library.

Comment: FYI, ABS is no longer needed now that AppCompat is stable. Just saying, because I made the same mistake and I'm sure other people reading this have too.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I also had a problem getting ActionBarSherlock running. I had an existing project, but it sounds like you simply want ABS From scratch. Here are step by step instructions of what to do :

**1)** Download ABS here: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

**2)** Extract ABS, you should have a directory in there called "actionbarsherlock". Copy that to your Android Studio workspace. and rename to `ActionBarSherlock (changed casing)` -- > I now have my Android Studio Projects under `\*documents*\Android Workspace\` As opposed to `\Eclipse Workspace\`

So you should now have something like :

`\*documents*\Android Workspace\ActionBarSherlock\`

Along with your main project maybe:

`\*documents*\Android Workspace\TestProject\`

**3)** Open Android Studio load your `TestProject` then goto `File> Import Module..`. Now navigate to ActionBarSherlock under `\*documents*\Android Workspace\ActionBarSherlock\`
Click Ok and next all the way to finish. It will ask if you want to set a dependancy to the new Module (or at least mine did) click OK

**4)** What i found at this point is that when compiling I was getting errors in `\ActionBarSherlock\test\` complaining about `Junit`. I simply deleted the `\Test\` directory from my ABS Module under project view. `Right click \test\ > Delete...`

**5)** you should now be able to compile without errors :)

Hopefully that helps someone.

Essentially though, I needed to re-download a completely fresh ABS, expunge my old project's ABS (which was probably quite old) then Import Module...

EDIT: This was written a while ago so I'm not sure how relevant it is today, but as Paulo mentions in the comments try these steps, and also have a read of the general import library to ABS thread over here --> [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Comment: Simply clicking "this is useful" is not enough: THANK YOU!!! Just what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @CJe I'm glad you found it useful :)

Comment: UPDATE: Yes, this approach added ABS but when I tried too use it, it gave errors saying SherlockActivity.app, etc not found. After lots of looking around, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio (WITH some minor tweaks), got it working for me!

Comment: Make sure you add the ActionBarSherlock as a dependency of your main application.

Answer (score 12):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}
```

Found that from [ActionBar Sherlock with Android Studio 0.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945111/actionbar-sherlock-with-android-studio-0-2-2)

This question should be closed and linked as dupe. The above line adds the lib as maven dependency and therefore doesn't need to be included as a whole project. It also lets you control the version from one line. Fantastic fix. Thank the OP on the other question for posting.

Here is a sample project on github as well:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Gradle-Sample

The support library version number is not critical make sure you always use the most up to date version permitted by your project. The actual inclusion of the support jar as a whole is NOT optional

Comment: I had many errors regarding ActionBarSherlock and Greadle, eventually what  worked for me was to change the dependencies to:
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile project(':ActionBarSherlock')
}

Answer (score 2):

wired00's answer is good, but I had the following error during compilation :

```
android-apt-compiler: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'
```

It happened that ActionBarSherlock was compiled as an application project. It was a bit hard to find the check box to compile it as a library, so in case you have the same problem, go to :

**File > Project structure > Facets > ActionBarSherlock >** Check "Library module".

Comment: @kabuto178 - In File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies -> Add ActionBarSherlock as dependency. Not as Library. The error should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add ActionBarSherlock to my project by following this tutorial:

http://showlabor.blogspot.ca/2013/05/actionbarsherlock-in-android-studio-01.html

I also added ActionBarSherlock as a dependency of the project to fix compilation errors.

Comment: but this tutorail is on Linux OS, I m using windows 7 OS. can you provide a link regarding this please

Comment: @QadirHussain It applies to win7 also.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this problem, you just need to add the abs resource path to your project build file,just like below:

```
sourceSets {
main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res','../../ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/res']
        }
    }
```

so, i compile with no error again.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach by merging ABS res folder with my res folder and using ActionBarSherlock.jar as a global lib.

Works well so far! But this is a hack since I was fed up of doing many things and I can't use Gradle since some of the other developers using Eclipse ADT without Gradle.