# Cannot add dependency in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I exported my project from eclipse to genereate gradle build files and then imported as non-android project to android studio. I added actionbarsherlock dependency to the gradle file and synched and it always shows

Error:Failed to find: com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        }
    }


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

            // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
            // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
            // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
            // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
            // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
            // by a similar customization.
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }
    }
```

If i run the project i get this error

**Error log**

```
> Could not find com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/Applications/ADT Bundle/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.pom
     file:/Applications/ADT Bundle/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar
     file:/Applications/ADT Bundle/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.pom
     file:/Applications/ADT Bundle/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar
```

I couldnt find any solution that would help me with this issue...

Comment: see how add library here hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577241/installing-actionbarsherlock-with-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried import ABS again in Android Studio? I'm not sure your previous eclipse project's import will take effect in Android Studio. 
You can try File->Project Structure, and click the add button to add ABS again.